# Multiple IF Functions with Tick Boxes

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Is there a formula I use that states, if either check box is checked in row 1, B2, C2, OR D2 (so any of the 3) - it appears in E2 as Present. If none are checked, then absent. The formula I've been using is =IF(B2=FALSE, "ABSENT","PRESENT") but I can't get it to apply to any of the 3 boxes.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In column E

```
=if(B9=true,"Present",if(C9=true,"Present",if(D9=true,"Present","Absent")))
```

Copied down through the range in column E as required.

Why this works: Nested `=IF(TRUE,FALSE)` is examined in turn. So if the first condition is TRUE it performs the first TRUE condition, if FALSE it looks to the next nested IF() which is again examined on the same basis through the formula. If no condition is TRUE then the FALSE condition will ultimately apply.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula in cell `E2`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B7="","", 
              IF((B2:B7=TRUE)+(C2:C7=TRUE)+(D2:D7=TRUE), 
                      "PRESENT", "ABSENT")))
```

The formula will auto expand to all cells below it.

[image]